# Get top 5 created subsites in sharepoint without for loop

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I need an easy way to get the latest 5 created webs.

I know every web has a Created Date property.

I would like to do this without a foreach becahse there can be 1000 subsites.

Any idea?

```
 using (SPSite clientSiteCollection = new SPSite(currentUrl))
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in clientSiteCollection.AllWebs.Select(c => c.Properties["WebTemplate"] == "xx").OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).Take(5))
                {
```

Comment: Linq?  Order by Created Date desc and do a Take 5.

Comment: Added the syntax below let see how it works for you.

Comment: I'd normally suggest you use `AllWebs.WebsInfo` to get details like this, but unfortunately [`SPWebInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebinfo.aspx) doesn't seem to include a created date.

Comment: Re your immediate LINQ problem, you need to use `Where` instead of `Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq.  It would be something similar to this.

```
var newestSites = clientSiteCollection.AllWebs.OrderByDescending(p=>p.CreatedDate).ToList().Take(5);
// Now NewestSites is a collection of your top 5 newest created Sites.
```

Comment: This will go to the database repeatedly to open every single `SPWeb`, and not dispose any of them. Also in general with LINQ, if you want a list, make `ToList` your last method call.

Comment: With SPSite wrapped in a using statement, and each SPWeb being a property of that object once your done with your queries the SPSite object will be disposed of along with all the SPWeb objects.

Comment: @Rawling another approach?

Comment: @all please ssee the edited code, first I need to filter by a specif property bag, and then order by created date and take the 5, however I cant access the Created property after the select , it says bool does not contain extension method for created

Comment: @Bearcat9425 please see my updated code, I need to filter something first, before ordering and taking the 5. but wont work. bool does not contain extension method for created

Comment: @Bearcat No, if you iterate through `AllWebs`, then dispose the `SPSite`, all the `SPWeb` objects you opened will _not_ be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you build the KeywordQuery against SharePoint Search, where you specify that you only want "SPWeb" as search results and passing managed Property "Created" as criteria in the query. Something like this:

```
myQuery.QueryText = "contentclass:STS_web Created>6/1/2013"
```

Building KeywordQuery: http://dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/03/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-2013-search-keywordquery-class.aspx

In addition, you configure KeywordQuery that you want only 5 results:

```
myQuery.RowLimit = 5;
```

and that you want them sorted by "Created" in Descending order:

```
myQuery.SortList.Add("Created", SortDirection.Descending);
```

Sorting Search Queries: http://dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/01/03/how-to-sort-search-queries-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx